# Jquery slide with next and previous button, I need a piece of code that resets the slide to the first image

Tags: jquery, html

I am pretty new to jquery and am hoping someone could help me out with this little problem I am having. I am pretty positive this particular piece of code I want is easy for people with more experience, so hence this post.

I have a Jquery slide with both a next and a previous button. When I go to other parts of the site and come back, the slide is still on the picture that was last shown (I turned of the automatic slide). In this example, when I go to other parts of the site, the slide is hidden.

So what I would like to have, is a piece of code that makes the image slide reset to the first image.

This is the jquery and html that I have used:

Jquery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            var pages = $('#container #bottom .content .projects .tab .info .slide li'), current = 0;
            var currentPage, nextPage;

            $('#container #bottom .content .projects .tab .info .knoppen .buttons').click(function() {
                currentPage = pages.eq(current);
                if ($(this).hasClass('prevPic')) {

                    if (current <= 0)
                        current = pages.length - 1;
                    else
                        current = current - 1;
                } else {
                    if (current >= pages.length - 1)
                        current = 0;
                    else
                        current = current + 1;
                }
                nextPage = pages.eq(current);
                currentPage.hide();
                nextPage.show();
            });
        });
```

HTML slide:

```
<div class="slide">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><img src="img/portfolio/TM_Logos_huisstijl01.gif" />
                                            </li>
                                            <li><img src="img/portfolio/TM_Logos_huisstijl02.gif" />
                                            </li>
                                            <li><img src="img/portfolio/TM_Logos_huisstijl03.gif" />
                                            </li>
                                            <li><img src="img/portfolio/TM_Logos_huisstijl04.gif" />
                                            </li>
                                            <li><img src="img/portfolio/TM_Logos_huisstijl05.gif" />
                                            </li>
                                            <li><img src="img/portfolio/TM_Logos_huisstijl06.gif" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
```

I hope I provided enough information and am thankful of anyone who would like to take a peak :)

Greetings,
L.

Edit, this is the code used to scroll between projects, which makes the image slide hidden when in another project:

```
    $(".project.buttons.panel").delegate(".button", "click", function onclick() {
    var currentProject$ = $(".projects .current.project")
        , project = "", nextProject$, previousProject$;
    if (this.getAttribute("href").match(/#next$/)) {
        nextProject$ = currentProject$.next();
        // If there is no next project,
        //  then check the first project
        if (nextProject$.length === 0) {
            nextProject$ = $(".projects .project:first");
        }
        // If there is still no project,
        //  then there is something wrong
        if (nextProject$.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Unable to find a project");
        }
        project = nextProject$.attr("id");
    } else if (this.getAttribute("href").match(/#previous$/)) {
        previousProject$ = currentProject$.prev();
        // If there is no previous project,
        //  then check the last project
        if (previousProject$.length === 0) {
            previousProject$ = $(".projects .project:last");
        }
        // If there is still no project,
        //  then there is something wrong
        if (previousProject$.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Unable to find a project");
        }
        project = previousProject$.attr("id");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unknown command");
    }
    hashInfo.change({ project: project, tab: 1 });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Little more information would be helpful. How do you show and hide the slide?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your inquiry :) I have added the code that is used to make the slide show and hide. I hope this is enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do, when u scroll between projects just always show the first li in the slide div?

```
$('.slide li').hide().filter(':eq(0)').show();
```